# C# .NET 4.0 App Works in Win 7 Pro 64-bit, not Win 8 Pro 64-bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, xna

I created a silly little "game" in Visual Studio 2010 to play around a bit with XNA and teach myself game development. All it does is cycle colors and bounce around some little balls. I have the project built for .NET 4.0 Client Profile. This game works perfectly in Windows 7 with no trouble at all. However, when trying to run it in Windows 8, it crashes immediately. In the error window, I see the following:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: BouncingBalls.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    51ba1d0b
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.2.9200.16451
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50988950
  Exception Code:   e0434352
  Exception Offset: 00014b32
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: f3d5
  Additional Information 4: f3d5be0cad2787556264647dc02181c3
```

I also ran it through the debugger, and this is what I see:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BouncingBalls\BouncingBalls.exe
Symbol search path is: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BouncingBalls\Content
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000000`00b20000 00000000`00b2a000   BouncingBalls.exe
ModLoad: 000007fe`249e0000 000007fe`24b9e000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`77780000 00000000`778d7000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`77730000 00000000`77775000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`776d0000 00000000`7772a000   C:\Windows\system32\wow64win.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`776c0000 00000000`776c8000   C:\Windows\system32\wow64cpu.dll
(f84.efc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!LdrQueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI+0x774:
000007fe`24a9ada0 cc              int     3
```

After hitting F5:

```
0:000> g
ModLoad: 00000000`00e90000 00000000`00fc6000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
ModLoad: 00000000`74f60000 00000000`75090000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
ModLoad: 00000000`00e90000 00000000`00fc6000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
ModLoad: 00000000`00e90000 00000000`00fdc000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
ModLoad: 00000000`71260000 00000000`712aa000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`74f60000 00000000`75090000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`755e0000 00000000`75686000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
(f84.efc): WOW64 breakpoint - code 4000001f (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll_77780000!LdrResolveDelayLoadsFromDll+0xa86:
7782054d cc              int     3
```

I've been searching online for answers, but nothing seems to really apply to the situation correctly or makes sufficient sense. I've even tried running it from locations other than what's stated (the desktop), but always the same result. I'm not sure where to go from here to resolve this.

Comment: Slightly OT, but you may find this interesting : http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/Windows8LOBDeploymentLsquostoryrsquo.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out I'm an idiot, so downvotes will be fine. =P

Apparently, as I was unaware, the reason it wasn't working on Windows 8 was the Win8 machine didn't have the XNA 4 Redist installed whereas it was installed on my Win7 machine. Once I got it installed the game worked normally.